# Switch, same value for multiple case

Tags: php, switch-statement

```
switch ($i) {
    case A:
        $letter = 'first';
        break;
    case B:
        $letter = 'first';
        break;
    case C:
        $letter = 'first';
        break;
    case D:
        $letter = 'second';
        break;
    default:
        $letter = 'third';
}
```

**Is there any way to shorten first three cases?**

They have the same values inside.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

```
switch ($i) {
    case A:
    case B:
    case C:
        $letter = 'first';
        break;
    case D:
        $letter = 'second';
        break;
    default:
        $letter = 'third';
}
```

Yep there is. If there's no `break` after a `case`, the code below the next `case` is executed too.

Answer (score 13):

```
switch ($i) {
    case A:
    case B:
    case C:
        $letter = 'first';
        break;
    case D:
        $letter = 'second';
        break;
    default:
        $letter = 'third';
}
```